# How to access store instance within react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to differentiate different redux state changes and saw this github solution: [Redux-watch](https://github.com/jprichardson/redux-watch) In order to the watch function you're supposed to provide the redux store which can't figure out how to do. I'm passing the store down to this component through a provider for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need access to the store state in a component, you should be using [the `useSelector` hook](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) or [the `connect` higher-order component](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate).  Don't try to set up store subscriptions yourself in components - React-Redux does that for you already.